# Is there an ORM for Perl?

Tags: perl, orm

```
create table person
(
    name varchar(15),
    attr1 varchar(15),
    attr2 varchar(1),
    attr3 char(1),
    attr4 int
)
```

How I can use basic ORM in Perl by taking a simple table like the one above and mapping it to Perl objects?  Next I'd like to perform basic operations like select results using some criteria system Perl like syntax. eg.:

```
@myResults = findAll(attr1 == 3 && attr2 =~ /abc/);
```

Comment: DBIx::Class worked for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Rule #1, don't write your own.

There are quite a number of ORMs on CPAN, including ...

- [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class) - probably #1 in popularity at the moment
- [Rose::DB::Object](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object)
- [Fey::ORM](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Fey-ORM) - my own contribution, most notable for being [Moose](http://moose.perl.org/)-based, which means you get all the power of Moose in your ORM-based classes.

Comment: I was basically posting to say the same thing when I saw this. Perl is all about reusing existing code.

Comment: It's nice that Perl has 3 ways to do this.  However, can support compare and contrast the 3 libraries?  Popularity is one criteria.  Simplicity and time to use is another.

Comment: this'd probably best as a new question of its own.

Comment: It's easier to compare them for you if you tell us what's important to you. :)

Comment: You should edit the question to encapsulate the additional information you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

(Chiming late) Data::ObjectDriver (also on CPAN) provides great flexibility especially if partitioning and caching is on the list of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Of the suggestions I'd use DBIx::Class.  Here's some code to introspect a 50 table legacy database (with relationships specified in the schema):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader qw/ make_schema_at /;

make_schema_at("Zotero::Schema",
               {
                   # components => ['InflateColumn::DateTime'],
                   debug => 1,
                   relationships => 1,
                   dump_directory => './lib' ,
               },
               ["dbi:SQLite:dbname=../zotero.sqlite", "",""]);
```