# Automatic database schema generation and migration with Perl

Tags: database, perl, schema, mapping

In Ror or Django or web2py you can "describe" a database (as a set of classes that remaps to tables) and the framework (having being provided with a connection string to the desired database) generates the tables, fields, relations and in the case of RoR and web2py it also keeps it up-to-date (eg, removing a class drops the table, adding a property to the class triggers an "alter table add" etc).

Is there any Perl module that does the same? Eg, it takes the YAML/XML/JSON description of a database as input and modifies/generates the database schema accordingly?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281440/is-there-an-orm-for-perl and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281803/is-there-an-object-centric-perl-orm

Comment: i'm not looking for an orm. i don't want objects to remap my database, nor i want anything to be created by introspecting a database; in fact, i'm looking for the other way round: a database created by parsing some sort of configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the module  is [SQL::Translator::Parser::YAML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL::Translator::Parser::YAML), and here is some [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/SQL-Translator-0.11005/lib/SQL/Translator/Manual.pod#SERIALIZING_SCHEMAS)

Comment: I don't think this is what he is looking for.  The YAML parser just converts the parser to perl formats, but will not create the CREATE TABLE commands he is looking for.

Comment: SQL::Translator has parsers as well as producers, e.g. SQL::Translator::Producer::MySQL.  You use them in pairs, YAML as input MySQL (for example) as output.

Answer (score -2):

I have an alpha version GPL project that does this.  Though it is written in PHP, it can be invoked from Perl:

System("/path/to/triBuilder.php --yaml=....");

http://code.google.com/p/triangulum-db/